# Error when trying to grab invites of the guilds my bot is in

Tags: discord, discord.js

It somehow only works when I make a new channel, this does get irritating though considering people who will add my bot to their server won't make a new channel specifically for it.

Error:

```
{ DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Multiverse\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: 'Unknown Channel',
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/702061566601986049/invites',
  code: 10003,
  httpStatus: 404 }
```

Code I'm using:

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "!guildinv") {
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  guild.channels.cache.first().createInvite()
    .then(inv => console.log(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`)).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the first channel is a Category.

```js
const textChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === "text");
if(textChannel) textChannel.createInvite()
//if there is no textChannel found it could mean there is no *cached* text channel
//so you should prob make a fallback to fetch for a text channel
//then again I think all channels are cached so I'm not sure
```

Also an alternative is  `guild.fetchInvites();`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchInvites

Comment: Just woke up, played with the code and it finally worked! You're a lifesaver!